# Set input field default value with json_encode data

Tags: php, html, jquery

I am trying to set the default value for an input field with contents from the database, I have successfully fetched the data from the database but am confused on how to set the default value fetched from the database to the text field.
below is my php code which fetches the data from database:

```
function fetch_user_data() {  
global $wpdb;
$user_ID= get_current_user_id();   
$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM mydbtable WHERE user_id =  $user_ID "); 
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
 $data= $print->address;
echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

the input field looks like this:

```
<input field_type="text" name="myinputdield" id="myinputdield" value="" type="text" class="myinputdield">
```

I am trying to achieve it with jquery, but thats where i get lost, i know how to set the default fields manually but i will appreciate a guide on how to do it with the `json_encode($data);`
manually i achieve it with this simple jquery code:

```
jQuery("#myinputdield").attr("value", "defaultvalue");
```

I would like the default value to be the `json_encode($data);`

Comment: It's always wrong to call `echo json_encode()` in a loop. You should put all the values in an array, and then `echo json_encode($array);` at the end.

Comment: Do you have multiple inputs? How do they relate to the rows returned by the query?

Comment: @Barmar i want to set for only one field, that's why i haven't used an array

Comment: Then why did you use a `foreach` loop? Whenever I see that I assume there can be multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

Echo the JSON in the `jQuery` code:

```
jQuery("#myinputdield").attr("value", <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>);
```